# Can't make mongo work with rails on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, mongodb, mongoid

I'm trying to test mongoDB with rails, I'm pretty new with both.

Firstly, mongoDB is installed and working as a Windows Service.

Now, this is the step I did to create a simple app:

I created the app with this:

```
rails new MongoOnRailsBlog -O -J -T
```

Then I modified the gemfile and it now looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

gem 'mongoid'
gem 'bson_ext'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'devise'
gem 'haml'
gem 'haml-rails', :group => :development
gem 'hpricot', :group => :development
gem 'formtastic'
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

I modified the application.rb to add some generators:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

module MongoOnRailsBlog
  class Application < Rails::Application

    # Configure generators  
    config.generators do |g|  
      g.orm :mongoid  
      g.template_engine :haml  
    end  
  end
end
```

Then when I try to generate the mongoID config, with this:

```
rails generate mongoid:config
```

I have "cannot load file error"

```
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require': cannot load such file -- mongoid/version (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/devise-1.5.4/lib/devise/rails.rb:34:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) ineach_strongly_connected_component'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from E:/Dev/Projects/MongoOnRailsBlog/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:45:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I'm guessing it has to do with the good version of MongoID, but I have no idea where to verify, how to make sure its loading the good one...

Any suggestions as to where to look?

Thank.

Answer (score 0):

For future questions, please include exact version information for both Rails and Mongoid.  If you look at Gemfile.lock, it is most likely that bundler pulled in mongoid version 3.1.4.  If you look on Github and compare the commits for tag v3.1.4 versus branch master, it's clear that Rails 4 support is not included in v3.1.4.  An official release of Mongoid for Rails 4 is still pending.

So at this moment, I suggest that you retry with Rails 3 (currently 3.2.13) for good success.

Answer (score 0):

For now, put into your Gemfile:

```
gem 'mongoid', github: 'mongoid/mongoid'
```